# how to use react native mobile app with raspberry pi

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi

I want to build an app in react native that receives sensor data from Raspberry Pi 3B, displays it, and stores it in a Firebase backend. I can't find much information online about how I could do this. Do I receive the information from the RPi using Python and then transmit it to the app, or do I use JavaScript to collect the data? If the former, how do I use Python with react native, and if the latter, what Raspberry Pi library can I use with JavaScript?

Comment: This depends on your personal preference. You could do this wireless via bluetooth or over a wifi connection. You could build a server where both devices talk to each other using websockets. Up to you. If you want to go wired, you could use the serialport to directly communicate to react native.